# Convert 2 or more SVGs to PNG in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, png, offscreen-canvas

I'm using the below code to convert 1 SVG to PNG. I convert the SVG to canvas to PNG.

```
getDownloadURL = async () => {
          // Logic to convert SVG to PNG

          const svg = document.querySelector('#widget svg'),
            canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(svg.clientWidth*3, svg.clientHeight*3),
            svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            v = await Canvg.fromString(ctx, svgString, presets.offscreen());
          await v.render();
          const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob(),
            pngUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          return pngUrl;
}

download = filename => {
          const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.download = filename;
          getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            a.href = url;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            a.remove();
          });
        };
```

If I try to convert more than 1 SVG by replacing
`const svg = document.querySelector('#widget svg')` to `const svg = document.querySelector('#widget')` because `#widget` element has 2 SVGs, the resultant PNG has 2 SVGs **overlapping** each other.

How can I fix this overlapping issue?
It would be great if I can render the content of element `#widget` as it is on PNG.